# OpenID login problem in shared hosting server

Tags: dotnetopenauth, kigg

I uploaded my Kigg opensource asp.net mvc based website to a shared hosting server (I am using Asphostcentral). But I encounter a very strange problem when i was trying to login with my OpenID. There is a warning message like this:

"Could not load file or assembly PresentationFramework, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 or one of its dependencies. Access is denied."

But I can run my application well in my localhost. My website is: http://toupiao360.com 
you can try to login by click blue header region left linkbutton "登录", hope you guys can see this word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DotNetOpenAuth does indeed reference PresentationFramework.  It turns out that this assembly is useful for more than just WPF applications.  Namely, it's Xaml serialization capability, and a feature was added to DNOA 3.2 that leverages this.

However, DNOA can use it slightly differently so that I think it will avoid this error for you.  So I've filed [Issue 119](http://dotnetopenauth.net:8000/ticket/119) on your behalf so that DNOA 3.2.1 will hopefully resolve this issue for you.

In the meantime, you might try uploading PresentationFramework to your web site's Bin directory to see if that alleviates the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your information AArnott. 
I've tried the following steps:
1. Copied C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\PresentationFramework.dll to my website /bin folder.
2. I got an error when i call my website homepage.
Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)) 

3. I asked hosting company tech support grant me the READ and WRITE permission. Still doesn't work. 

I guess PresentationFramework.dll still have other dependencies dll.
So i guess i'd better try 2nd solution get DNOA 3.2.1. Can I get it in the near future soon?

Comment: I suspect PresentationFramework.dll requires full trust to run, so it probably must be in the GAC along with any of its dependencies.  
Another option you have is to actually use DNOA 3.1.x until DNOA 3.2.1 comes out, since 3.1.x didn't have the PresentationFramework.dll dependency.

Comment: Cool, after rolled back to DNOA 3.1 painful is gone now.

Comment: CodeYun, can you try out http://teamcity.dotnetopenauth.net:82/repository/download/bt25/217:id/DotNetOpenAuth-3.2.1.9243.zip and tell me if that works for you?  I want to make sure the next version of v3.2 fixes it so you don't have to be stuck with v3.1

Answer (score 0):

Check with your shared hosting company and make sure that the PresentationFramework assembly is available to your site.

Comment: Does DotNetOpenId reference anything from PresentationFramework? I thought PresentationFramework assembly is for windows application?